# More than one combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I choose the list name on the first ComboBox. Can't display elements on second combobox. (etc. x=[1,2,3] - y=[4,5,6,7] - z=[8,9] 
If x is selected on the first combobox, I want to see the x elements on the second combobox.)

```
İÇECEKLER = ['Su', 'Maden Suyu', 'Çay', 'Kahve', 'Nescafe', 'Kola', 'Fanta', 'Sprite']
YİYECEKLER = ['Simit', 'Poğaça', 'Açma', 'Boyoz', 'Tahinli', 'Kumru', 'Tost', 'Kumpir']
TATLILAR = ['Sütlaç', 'Puding', 'Aşure', 'Revani', 'Pasta', 'Künefe', 'Waffle', 'Tiramisu']
DİĞER = ['KDV', 'Servis Bedeli']

value0 = StringVar ()
value1 = StringVar ()
value2 = StringVar ()
value3 = StringVar ()

KategoriKutu = Frame (root, width = 1000, height = 300, bd = 16, relief = 'raise')
KategoriKutu.pack (side = TOP)
Kategori = Frame (KategoriKutu, width = 800, height = 300, bd = 8, relief = 'raise')
Kategori.pack (side = LEFT)

KategoriSeç = ttk.Combobox (Kategori, textvariable = value0, state = 'readonly', width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
KategoriSeç ['values'] = ('', 'İÇECEKLER', 'YİYECEKLER', 'TATLILAR', 'DİĞER')
KategoriSeç.current()
KategoriSeç.grid (row = 0, column = 0)

ÜrünSeç = ttk.Combobox (Kategori, textvariable = value1, state = 'readonly', width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
ÜrünSeç ['values'] = ('', )
ÜrünSeç.current()
ÜrünSeç.grid (row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the spot that confused my mind.

```
a = ['Su', 'Maden Suyu', 'Çay', 'Kahve', 'Nescafe', 'Kola', 'Fanta', 'Sprite']
b = ['Simit', 'Poğaça', 'Açma', 'Boyoz', 'Tahinli', 'Kumru', 'Tost', 'Kumpir']
c = ['Sütlaç', 'Puding', 'Aşure', 'Revani', 'Pasta', 'Künefe', 'Waffle', 'Tiramisu']
d = ['KDV', 'Servis Bedeli']
```

I have a Total of four lists, and they all have different elements.

```
a_combo = ttk.Combobox(Kategori, state = 'readonly',width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
a_combo ['values'] = ('', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
a_combo.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
a_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda e: set_next_combo(e,b_combo,a))

b_combo = ttk.Combobox(Kategori, state = 'readonly', width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
b_combo.grid (row = 1, column = 0)
```

If I chose which list on the first ComboBox, I failed to fetch the list elements I selected on the second ComboBox.

if first combobox is 'a' selected, second combobox 'a' elements or 'b' selected 'b' elements or 'c' selected 'c' elements need to arrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a dictionary out of your lists and have your `<<ComboboSelected>>` event call the corresponding list.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
test_dict = {
"a" : ['Su', 'Maden Suyu', 'Çay', 'Kahve', 'Nescafe', 'Kola', 'Fanta', 'Sprite'],
"b" : ['Simit', 'Poğaça', 'Açma', 'Boyoz', 'Tahinli', 'Kumru', 'Tost', 'Kumpir'],
"c" : ['Sütlaç', 'Puding', 'Aşure', 'Revani', 'Pasta', 'Künefe', 'Waffle', 'Tiramisu'],
"d" : ['KDV', 'Servis Bedeli']}

KategoriKutu = Frame (root, width = 1000, height = 300, bd = 16, relief = 'raise')
KategoriKutu.pack (side = TOP)
Kategori = Frame (KategoriKutu, width = 800, height = 300, bd = 8, relief = 'raise')
Kategori.pack (side = LEFT)

def set_next_combo(event,widget):
    result = test_dict.get(a_combo.get(),[])
    widget["values"] = result
    widget.set(result[0] if result else " ")

a_combo = ttk.Combobox(Kategori, state = 'readonly',width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
a_combo ['values'] = ('', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
a_combo.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
a_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda e: set_next_combo(e,b_combo))

b_combo = ttk.Combobox(Kategori, state = 'readonly', width = 16, justify = "center", font = ('arial', 30, 'bold'))
b_combo.grid (row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't really think This method. Thank You @Henry Yik